# Play multiple ads using RAF roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am working on Roku app using Scene Graph component. I want to play multiple ads using RAF but it playing only one ad at a time. Please provide suggestion to resolve it. [Here the ads feed URL](http://fusioniprojects.com/rnd/addpod/adpods.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using RokuCo's default ad server (as shown in https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Integrating+the+Roku+Advertising+Framework#IntegratingtheRokuAdvertisingFramework-GettingStarted ), you'll be getting only one pod per request.

If you want to show >1 per break, i can think of two options:

- Either use a different back-end with `raf.setAdUrl(myAdUrl)`
- or call `raf.getAds()` twice and manually stitch in `adPods` before showing them with a single `.showAds(adPods)` call

PS. see also https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=98231 - possible continuation on the subject